# What is the time complexity of T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+T(n-3)+T(n-4) . . . . T(n-(n-1))?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, time-complexity, big-o

I was having a recursive algorithm. Without using memoization, this is my recurrence relation. How to calculate the time complexity?

Comment: It's probably O(n). Posting the actual algorithm would be necessary to solve, since T is an unknown function. If T(n) runs in constant time, O(n) is correct.

Comment: @Triptych, that is not true. Also the last phrase is a contradiction.

Comment: A simple approach that works here is to compute some T(n) for small n, and then see if you can spot the pattern (or put it in OEIS if you can't).

Comment: @Triptych T(n) doesn't "run". T is a function in the mathematical sense, and T(n) is a number.

Comment: Yup you guys are right. I misread.

Answer (score 8):

T(2) = T(1)

T(3) = T(2) + T(1) = T(1) + T(1) = 2*T(1)

T(4) = T(3) + T(2) + T(1) = 2*T(1) + T(1) + T(1) = 4*T(1)

T(5) = T(4) + T(3) + T(2) + T(1) = 4*T(1) + 2*T(1) + T(1) + T(1) = 8*T(1)

...

**T(n) = 2<sup>(n-2)</sup>*T(1)**

Answer (score 0):

You have T(n) = sum(T(i) i=1..n-1)

Then for n>1, T(n+1) - T(n) = sum(T(i) i=1..n) - sum(T(i) i=1..n-1) = T(n)

So for n>2, T(n) = 2T(n-1). So T(n) is some multiple of 2^n for n>2. A simple computation shows the multiple is T(1)/4 (and this happens to also work for n=2).